# Why Maven ignore logging options?

Tags: gitlab, maven

Can you explain why maven ignores log options and output info log level instead of warning?

```
$ mvn ${MAVEN_CLI_OPTS} clean install test -Drevision=${MAVEN_REVISION} -Dchangelist=${MAVEN_CHANGELIST} -Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.defaultLogLevel=warn -Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.log.org.apache.maven.cli.transfer.Slf4jMavenTransferListener=WARN --settings ${MAVEN_SETTINGS_XML}
...
14:08:23.521 [main] INFO org.springframework.test.context.support.AnnotationConfigContextLoaderUtils - Could not detect default configuration classes for test class [ru.bankffin.dss.hard_check.core.service.HardCheckServiceTest]: HardCheckServiceTest does not declare any static, non-private, non-final, nested classes annotated with @Configuration.
14:08:23.631 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider - Identified candidate component class: file [/builds/ffinpay/dss/dss-hard-check/target/classes/ru/bankffin/dss/hard_check/core/Application.class]
14:08:23.632 [main] INFO org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper - Found @SpringBootConfiguration ru.bankffin.dss.hard_check.core.Application for test class ru.bankffin.dss.hard_check.core.service.HardCheckServiceTest
14:08:23.712 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper - @TestExecutionListeners is not present for class [ru.bankffin.dss.hard_check.core.service.HardCheckServiceTest]: using defaults.
14:08:23.713 [main] INFO org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper - Loaded default TestExecutionListener class names from location [META-INF/spring.factories]: [org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener
```

I've tried to use -Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.defaultLogLevel=warn in MAVEN_OPTS and in command mvn ${MAVEN_CLI_OPTS} clean install testdirctly, but it doesn't maqke some result.
I don't need info loglevel, because this logs exceed log cache on gitlub runner.

part of .gitlab-ci.yml below:

```
stages:
  - build
  ...

# Variables
.maven_vars: &maven_vars
  MAVEN_CLI_OPTS: "--batch-mode --errors --log-file target/client-quality_check.log"
  MAVEN_OPTS: "-Dmaven.repo.local=.m2/repository -Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.defaultLogLevel=warn -Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.log.org.apache.maven.cli.transfer.Slf4jMavenTransferListener=WARN"
...
# Jobs templates
.build_binary_definition: &build_binary_definition
  image: maven:3.8.5-openjdk-17
  stage: build
  services:
    - alias: docker
      name: docker:19.03.5-dind 
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - target/*.jar
    - target/*.log
    expire_in: 1 week
  variables:
    <<:
      - *maven_vars
      - *docker_vars
  before_script:
    - export MAVEN_REVISION=$(if [[ ${IS_A_TAG} == "true" ]]; then echo "${CI_COMMIT_TAG#v}"; else echo "${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}"; fi)
    - export MAVEN_CHANGELIST=$(if [[ ${IS_A_TAG} != "true" ]]; then echo "-${CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA}"; fi)
    - export TZ="Europe/Moscow"
  script:
    - mvn ${MAVEN_CLI_OPTS} clean install test
      -Drevision=${MAVEN_REVISION}
      -Dchangelist=${MAVEN_CHANGELIST}
      --settings ${MAVEN_SETTINGS_XML}
...
# Jobs
build-binary:
  <<:
    - *build_binary_definition
  rules:
    - *is_a_master_rule
    - *is_a_feature_rule
    - *is_a_tag_rule
    - *is_a_mr_manual_rule
...
```

Comment: This may be an X-Y problem.  Please explain what the original problem you are trying to solve is.